# Perl packages: how to import classes into the 'use'r's namespace?

Tags: perl, exception, namespaces, package, perl-module

I'm working on a package that defines exceptions (using `Exception::Class::Nested`) for its 'parent' package.  I don't want the parent package to have to use the really long names, though, *and* I don't want to pollute any other namespace.

So what I'd like to do is export the last element of the class names into the namespace of the package that `use`d the exception package.

For example, an excerpt from the exception package:

```
package Klass:Foo::Bar::Exceptions;
use vars qw( @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK ... );
@ISA = qw( Klass::Foo::Bar Exporter );
use Exception::Class::Nested 0.04 (
    'Klass::Foo::Bar::Exceptions::BaseClass' => {
        description => 'Base class for exceptions',
        'Klass::Foo::Bar::Exceptions::NameError' => {
            error => "I don't like your face"
        }
    }
);
```

The 'parent' package:

```
package Klass::Foo::Bar;
use Klass::Foo::Bar::Exceptions;
Klass::Foo::Bar::Exceptions::NameError->throw(error => "D'oh!");
my $e = NameError->new(error => 'Mwahaha!');
```

I'd *like* to export/import the exception class such that the second invocation (the `my $e` one) works as though `NameError` was defined in `Klass::Foo::Bar`, but I haven't figured it out yet.

(And before anyone says 'but `Exception::Class` has the nifty `alias` thingy,' I'll point out that the alias name is linked *specifically* to the exception's `throw` method, so I can't use that for non-auto-thrown `new` invocations..)

One thing I tried is putting this in the exception package's `importer` sub (`@snames` is either an array of the fully-qualified exception classes (*e.g.*, `'Klass::Foo::Bar::Exceptions::NameError'`), or just the tail end (*e.g.*, `'NameError'`):

```
my $caller = caller();
$caller ||= 'main';
my @snames = @{$EXPORT_TAGS{exceptions}};
for my $exc (@snames) {
    $exc =~ s/^.*:://;
    no strict qw(subs refs);
    *{"${caller}\:\:${exc}\:\:"} = \*{__PACKAGE__ . "\:\:${exc}\:\:"};
}
```

But this ends up requiring me to invoke the exceptions using `Klass::Foo::Bar::NameError` rather than just `NameError`.  It seems it works, but too well.

I *don't* want to import `NameError` into `main::`!

Typeglobs and symbol tables are still a bit mysterious to me, I'm afraid.

I'm sure there's a way to do what I want (or else I'm doing something that I shouldn't altogether, but let's leave that alone for now).  Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example `import` sub, you are aliasing package stashes, which is not going to do what you want.  Instead, you want to create subroutines with the shortened names that return the full package name:

```
sub import {
    my $caller = caller;
    for my $long (@{$EXPORT_TAGS{exceptions}}) { # for each full name
        my ($short) = $long =~ /([^:]+)$/;       # grab the last segment
        no strict 'refs';
        *{"$caller\::$short"} = sub () {$long};  # install a subroutine named 
                                                 # $short into the caller's pkg
                                                 # that returns $long
    }
}
```

Breaking apart that last line, `sub () {$long}` creates an anonymous subroutine that takes no arguments.  The code reference contains the single variable `$long` which retains the value it had during the loop iteration.  This is called a lexical closure, which basically means that the subroutine's compilation environment (`$long` and it's value) will persist as long as the subroutine does.

This anonymous subroutine is then installed into the caller's package with the `$short` name.  The fully qualified name of a subroutine in the caller's package is `caller::subname`, which `"$caller\::$short"` constructs. This is then dereferenced as a typeglob `*{ ... }`.  Assignment to a typeglob with a reference fills that slot of the typeglob.  So assigning a code reference installs the subroutine.

Put another way, the following subroutine declaration:

```
sub short () {'a::long::name'}
```

means the same thing as:

```
BEGIN {*{__PACKAGE__.'::short'} = sub () {'a::long::name'}}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that's doing, but it works.  I'll have to study this in order to understand it.  Thanks!!!